# Starcarft II Relapse, Protoss Tactics

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

I was able to get away from Starcraft II for a while (6 months or so). Now that I relapsed I see that there were many updates. Some of these changed unit properties etc.

I was wondering if anything substantial has changed in tactics. Do the new unit updates have new tactics specific to once useless units like archons etc?

Thanks

Comment: I'd vote to close as too localized... if I could

Comment: I suppose the question could be refactored as "What tactics for Protoss/PvZ/PvT have arisen since patch X?" or something...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Protoss there three changes that really effect you.

- Warp Gate research time has been increased by 20 seconds
- Sentry build time from gateways has decreased by 5
- Archons are now Massive Units, with range 3.

Also note that infesters do the same damage with fungal growth in half the time and it now stops you from using Blink as well.

Forgot to mention that Khaydarin Amulet has been removed from the game - quite big as you can no longer warp in storms.

Not so important, units that exit a Motherships Vortex are immune from damage from 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Tactically speaking, this means slightly fewer 4gate all-ins, archons are used much more (being massive, they aren't affected by marauder slow, and stomp forcefields), and HTs must be babysat more carefully. Storm drops with warp prism mean warping in the HTs *before* the drop, so they have enough energy for storm. And during a battle you can't just warp in a quick HT to get a storm. And people have stopped crossing their fingers hoping for the old archon toilet.

Comment: Archon + Chargelot is SO fun now.  At least in lower leagues, where I rightfully belong, people are very slow to counter them if you can last long enough to get a couple of bases up to produce Archons in healthy numbers.